# Where can I find a list of GMO foods that are allowed to be grown or imported to Europe?

Tags: european-union, gmo

I want to learn about GMO products that could be sold or cultivated in the European Union.

Is there a list of GMO foods that are allowed to be imported or grown in EU countries?

Comment: Nearly everything you are eating today is a GMO, many things now since centuries ago and many of those do not even exist in nature. The only difference between old GMOs and new GMOs is that new GMOs are studied and produced scientifically in a lab, under strict monitoring and testing, while your average tomato has been GMOed empirically and without caring about its effect on health and environment (which was a non issue, hundreds years ago)

Comment: @motoDrizzt Well, GMOs from the olden days were more about making foods more digestible, available and easier to grow, and these days it's reversed because the reasons for it are completely different and science is much more advanced than crossing sour and sweet cherries like my grandparents did. I could rant more about that (based on actual science, not opinionated zealot blogs), but I don't think this is the place to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this is the list](http://ec.europa.eu/food/dyna/gm_register/index_en.cfm) you are looking for (Genetically Modified Organisms allowed within the EU). The web app allows the filter by category and keywords, but also can provide no filter values and see all products.

Also, [this article](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/headlines/society/20151013STO97392/eight-things-you-should-know-about-gmos) provides some quick info about how GMOs are handled within the EU.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but like all the information I have found so far, it only covers corn and soya. I'm interested in apples, potatoes, broccoli, and a few other things instead, and that's what I cannot find. Perhaps you have a source for those foods as well?